# WCF for REST

Tags: wcf, rest

Is wcf a viable REST solution?  It prevents you from using some special characters like # so requesting tag/c# does not work.  is there a work around, is this by design?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rest%20wcf

Answer (score 1):

REST has nothing to do with URI naming conventions. So if you want arbitrary text in your URIs, you can at the very least just use a urlsafe base64 encoding for anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think its going to be difficult to find a place for REST given how WCF was designed. Remember, one of WCF's major strengths comes indirectly from its use of SOAP.  It allows web services to be accessible on any transport, HTTP, TCP, MSMQ, etc., through simple configuration.  REST has explicit dependence on HTTP, making it transport-dependent.  So REST web services would be a little bit at odds with that transport flexibility designed into the core of WCF.

I *do* think that WCF needs to find a place for REST web services, as it *is* a form of communication. However, its going to be difficult to carve out a place in the framework that makes working with REST a "natural" process; and will that negate the work that went in to making WCF what it is today?